# Why is the unit separator (ASCII 31) invisible in terminal output?

Tags: terminal, ascii

The unit separator ASCII character (ASCII 31, octal 37), is visible in Vim as a `^_`. But if I print the same file to the terminal, the character is invisible. This causes the fields on a line to get stuck together:

```
# In Vim and less:

first field^_second field^_last field

# cat the same file to terminal:
cat delim.txt
first fieldsecond fieldlast field

# print 2nd field with awk 
cat delim.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\037"} {print $2}'
second field
```

I suppose I can make the unit separator visible with cat -v:

```
cat -v delim.txt
first field^_second field^_last field
```

But this is rather cumbersome. Why doesn't the unit separator have a visible representation when printed to stdout in the Bash shell? I can't even copy and paste the shell output correctly; the unit separator gets lost in the process.

Comment: Not all characters are printable, unit separator is one of these. Some editors will display it in some way to make editing possible. You need to translate it into a sequence of printable characters, and maybe a different font/colour, to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: ASCII codes under 31, and 127, are intended to cause a terminal or device to do something (hence why they are called control codes), or stand for something in a protocol (like EOT or SOH), as opposed to displaying something. It hearkens back when terminals were typewriter-like devices and things like telling a teletype to carriage-return were physically needed. Editors may choose to render them using "^" notation since you are editing something and don't want to terminal to actually do what the control codes are asking.

Comment: @LawrenceC: Code 127 actually intended to cause a terminal to do *nothing*,  If one was punching a tape and made a mistake, one would hit a button to back up the tape by one space and hit "rub-out", to punch all eight holes.  When the reader encountered the all-holes-punched character, it would send it over the wire but the recipient could just ignore it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The unit separator (`US`) character, also known as `IS1`, is in the `cntrl` character class and is **not** in the `print` character class. It is a control character that is intended for organizing text into groups, *for programs that are designed to make use of that information*. In general, non-printable characters are probably going to be interpreted and rendered differently in different programs or environments.

The reason you are seeing it represented as `^_` in Vim is because Vim is an interactive editor. It can freely render non-printable characters however it wants, as long as the correct binary character is written to disk.

You cannot get the same behavior in the shell because Unix shell programs are written to operate on and pass plain text to each other. When you `cat` a file, the text that is written to the terminal must be what is actually in the file.

So that leaves it to the terminal device to interpret the character. And it turns out that some terminal emulators **do** render the `US` character differently from others. In `gnome-terminal` (or any `vte`-based terminal), the character will be rendered as a box containing the hex code `001F`. In `xterm` or `rxvt`, the character is indeed invisible.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say `US` is *totally* invisible. When I insert that character into a terminal with `Ctrl+/` (confirmed via `<C-v><C-/>`), it deletes an unpredictable amount of text on the line. I don't fully understand its behavior, but it seems to mainly have some sort of "reverse tab" effect where instead of inserting a number of spaces, it deletes a number of characters, but then sometimes it randomly inserts text, so it's confusing.

Comment: As of Debian 10 (gnome-terminal v.3.30.2) the separator characters are invisible but in Debian 9 it was fine...

Comment: @BradenBest In most shells, incl. [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh], `^_` is bound to `undo`.

Comment: @MarlonRichert Good to know

Comment: @SylvainLeroux's answer shows how to enter `^_` in Bash, with `$'\c_'` .https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128075/268154

Answer (score 10):

The unit separator is in the ASCII range of [Control Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators), and therefore does not (or should not usually) have a visual representation.

Vim and some other editors display them, so you can edit them. As you noticed, `cat -v` displays it too. The man page shows, that `-v` is the short form of `--show-nonprinting`, which causes it to replace the non-printing characters with a printable representation, which is not the original content of the file and might therefore cause trouble, if the output is actually to another program.

The representation you see already hints it's a control character: a character prepended with a `^` is a common notation for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the character, which is the key combination that produces this character in a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> will let you input the unit separator in vim, for example. But another editor or some GUI viewer might display the hex code, a placeholder or something completely different.

As your terminal does not print the control characters, it is also not copied when selecting the text (the whitespace characters like newline and tab are an exception here, which are control characters too). Another example of control characters in the terminal that are usually ignored when copying are color codes, which are an `ESC` character followed by the code for coloring the text.

So to show the characters on your terminal, there is no other way than to use a program that replaces the unit separator with some printable character.

Answer (score 4):

A little bit at the margin of the other (very good) answers, if you want to alter *only* the control character `^_` when displaying the file content, you might want to *transliterate* it using the `tr` utility (and a little bit of bash-compatible syntax):

```
# Replace the control character US (^_) by *one* other character
$ cat my.file | tr $'\c_' ':'
```

If you need to replace that control character by its "expanded" form, you will need `sed` instead:

```
# Replace the control character US (^_) by any string
cat /tmp/f | sed s/$'\c_'/^_/g
```

Please note the syntax `$'\cX'`: this syntax inform your (bash-compatible shell) to replace the corresponding control character. See [wikipedia for a list of control characters alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) using the "caret notation". If you don't like that syntax, you might prefer using the octal `$'\037'` or hexadecimal `$'\x1f'` notation instead.